# VBScript read multiple filenames from txt file and list which do not exist in directory

Tags: arrays, vbscript, type-mismatch, fso

I am new to VB scripting, and I was trying to find a way to:

1. Read a list of file names written as lines of text inside a particular text file.
2. Check if those files exist in the same directory as the script.
3. Write the name of the files that do not exist to an output file (missing.txt)

From my research, it seems that a good approach would be to use FSO and read the entire text file, creating an array, then looping through to check if the file exists in the directory, and then logging to "missing.txt" if it doesn't.

However, doing it this way, wouldn't there be a type mismatch because the file name in the .txt is a string and the files in the directory themselves are objects?

How would I compare that? I can understand this conceptually, but I have no idea where to start with the syntax.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Start by writing a script that reads in the file names and prints them out. Once you have that working, try figuring out how to check for the existence of the file. Show us some code and we can help you.

Answer (score 5):

As you have stated that you are new to vbscript, and you appear to be new to Stack Overflow, I thought I would try to offer you some assistance.

It is not necessary for you to store the entire file as an array. All you need to do is process your input file line by line as text: check if each line of text exists as a filename.

Let's assume the following details for our example:

### filelist.txt      {The file that will contain the listing of files to find}

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file7.txt
```

---

### Directory Listing    {The folder you will be running the script from}

```
 Directory of C:\lazy-code-handed-over-on-silver-plate\files

 06/06/6666  06:66 PM    <DIR>          .
 06/06/6666  06:66 PM    <DIR>          ..
 06/06/6666  06:66 PM               666 file1.txt
 06/06/6666  06:66 PM               666 file2.txt
 06/06/6666  06:66 PM               666 file4.txt
 06/06/6666  06:66 PM               666 file5.txt
               4 File(s)           2664 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   6,666,666,666,666 bytes free
```

---

### Our example

The `filelist.txt` file contains `file1.txt` `file2.txt` `file3.txt` `file7.txt`.

The directory **does not** contain `file3.txt` or `file7.txt`.

Our expected output from this script based on these parameters is as follows:

### missing.txt   {The resultant output file that lists missing files}

```
file3.txt
file7.txt
```

---

## **The Script**

Here's a script to help you achieve this (I have added comments off to the far right of each relevant line):

```
Option Explicit                                                               ' .. Just coz.
Const forReading = 1                                                          ' Set our constants for later.
Const forWriting = 2                                                          ' ....

Dim inputFile, outputFile, fso, fileList, logFile, fileSpec                   ' Dimension our variables

inputFile = "filelist.txt"                                                    ' Our input file
outputFile = "missing.txt"                                                    ' Our output file

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")                          ' Set up fso
Set fileList = fso.OpenTextFile(inputFile, forReading)                        ' Open our input file for reading
If Not (fso.FileExists(outputFile)) Then fso.CreateTextFile(outputfile)       ' Create output file if it doesn't exist
Set logFile = fso.OpenTextFile(outputFile, forWriting)                        ' Open up our output file for writing later

Do while not fileList.AtEndOfStream                                           ' While we have lines to process do this loop
    fileSpec = fileList.ReadLine()                                            ' Read in line of text as variable fileSpec
    If Not (fso.FileExists(fileSpec)) Then                                    ' If it doesnt exist ....
        logFile.writeline (fileSpec)                                          ' ....Write it out to the output file
    End If 
Loop

fileList.close                                                                ' Clean up
logFile.close                                                                 ' ..
```

I hope this helps you. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: +1 for "Option xplicit" and *not* using an array for the file names.